# C++ Store Differences Between 2 Class Objects

Tags: c++

I want to store the differences between two objects of the same class.
I know that i can overwrite the `operator==` to compare two objects.

I now want to know if there is a nicer way to get the differences between two objects than in the following example:

```
class ExampleClass {
public:
    ExampleClass();

    friend std::vector<std::string> compare(const ExampleClass& other) {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        if(attribute1_ != other.attribute1_) {
            result.push_back("attribute1_");
        }
        // continue for other attributes
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::string attribute1_;
    int attribute2_;
```

}

In that example i had to compare each attribute.

Comment: Basically no, there is no nicer way. You need to compare each attribute.

Comment: Have you formalized the 'difference' of two objects of the class? If not, you should do that first.

Comment: You can use bitflags to indicate which fields are different.

Comment: No other way, except that you probably can create template and/or macro to make it more simple and readable.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. For the Formalization of the difference like Gaurav Singh mentioned i only want to get a string list of the attributes that are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a template guy, so I will show how macro can be used to simplify your task.

First you define macro something like this:

```
#define COMP_ATTR(attr) \
    if (attr != other.attr) { \
        result.push_back(#attr); \
    }
```

Then you can rewrite you compare function like this:

```
friend std::vector<std::string> compare(const ExampleClass& other) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    COMP_ATTR(attribute1_);
    // continue for other attributes
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the macro. I will let the question open for maybe one or two days. If no other one mentioned something helpfull i mark your answer as the solution =)